# 'System program problem' and generally broken Ubuntu, unable to access files, etc

Tags: boot, package-management, backup, data-recovery, deja-dup

Today, Ubuntu crashed, and everything's gone wrong. I shut down my computer like usual, the proper way, but it just froze on my desktop background, and nothing else.

I finally decided the only way to sort it would be to perform a hard stop, but when I next tried to boot up, I got an error *System program problem*, and I couldn't click anything. After a minute or so, it'd go back to my login screen again, and still, nothing worked.

I attempted the recovery things and tried to copy my files from the root shell, but they were protected, so I ran `ecryptfs-mount-private`, but got told that the directory wasn't correctly set up.

I also tried using a live USB installation to get my files, but after getting past the permissions with `chmod` I had the same issue. I ran the damage check in the Live USB GRUB menu, and I was told that two files were broken. I tried getting there with Windows but you can't get Ubuntu files from Windows. I tried copying my files with the command line to my USB stick, but it kept saying `Ignored directory`. Deja-dup, which I'd used to back up my files, didn't work, and duplicity, through the root terminal, didn't either.

I was going to reinstall Ubuntu to another partition, but I don't know where to do it to.

I have a lot of my files backed up, but some haven't been done yet. I don't mind having to go through another installation of Ubuntu, but I'd like to keep my files.

How can I recover those files? I'm running Ubuntu 14.04 LTS.

Edit: I've just discovered GParted, so I'm giving that a go now.

Comment: For accessing your files through windows see this:http://www.howtogeek.com/112888/3-ways-to-access-your-linux-partitions-from-windows/ (I have used successfully ext2fsd)

Comment: Thanks, I've got it and I can see my home folder, but it's just showing me the readme for ecryptfs-mount-private, and the other things like that

Comment: If I understood right, your home folder is encrypted? If yes try this, http://www.howtogeek.com/116297/how-to-recover-an-encrypted-home-directory-on-ubuntu/

Comment: I tried that, but I got a system loop error. It doesn't matter now, as I found out about Ctrl+Alt+F1, so I logged in and copied my files to my web server using the terminal (which did work, it seems), then downloaded them to another computer, and I'm currently reinstalling Ubuntu. Thanks a lot for your time and help, nevertheless :)